# Sequence in linked list data for mysql version 5.4

Tags: mysql

I have the following table structure.

[image]

Here starting with cover_id=from_id I need the sequence of the items id's in a seperate column. The expected output is as follows:

[image]

So the sequencing here is like: when cover_id = from_id start the sequence(0) and get the to_id in that row(310237) and check this in the id column and mark that row as next number(1) in the sequence again get the to_id of that row(310238) and check back in id column and mark it as next number(2) and so on.. when there is no to_id/Null in the to_id sequencing will end.

I tried to use the self left join - it didn't worked.

```
select A.id,A.cover_id,A.from_id,A.to_id, B.id, B.cover_id, B.from_id,B.to_id
from tableA A left join tableA B on A.to_id = B.id where A.cover_id=4655709 order by A.to_id desc limit 10;
```

Added the create table and insert script for reference.

```
Create table TableA (
id int,
cover_id int,
from_id int,
to_id int
)

Insert into TableA(id, cover_id,from_id,to_id)
values(310241, 4655709, 3962705, 310242),
(310238,4655709,4208771,310239),
(310242,4655709,4549272,NULL),
(310237,4655709,4613179,310238),
(310239,4655709,4613184,310240),
(310240,4655709,4613186,310241),
(310236,4655709,4655709,310237)
```

Comment: Replace data screenshot with CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO.

Comment: @Akina Have added the script. Please check.

Comment: Original task needs a recursion which is not supported by your MySQL version - so the task may be solved only in iterational stored procedure format. But in your data `id` is always less then `to_id` by 1 or is null, and in final state `sequence` ordering and `to_id` (nulls last) ordering matches to each other - is it a rule? or it is random? Look at [the fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3664116ffc5cfbdaa822d1fde9e14c5f).